# I do not understand hiera.yaml and hiera

Tags: puppet, hiera

I cannot seem to figure out how access my hiera data
that I put into my yaml file.

Here is my hiera.yaml:

```
[root@vxx-osc4-ppt-001 puppetmaster]# cat /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera.yaml
---
:backends:
  - yaml
:hierarchy:
  - "%{pod_prefix}"
  - defaults
  - "%{clientcert}"
  - "%{environment}"
  - global

:yaml:
# datadir is empty here, so hiera uses its defaults:
# - /var/lib/hiera on *nix
# - %CommonAppData%\PuppetLabs\hiera\var on Windows
# When specifying a datadir, make sure the directory exists.
  :datadir:
```

After I changed the above file I restarted my 3.7 PE Puppet master 
like so:

```
[root@vxx-osc4-ppt-001 puppetmaster]# systemctl restart pe-httpd
```

Also I have these two yaml files that contain the key/value pair for
a classparameter, controller_vip_name.  So I have this ...

```
[root@vxx-osc4-ppt-001 puppetmaster]# grep "^controller_vip_name:" /var/lib/hiera/*yaml
/var/lib/hiera/defaults.yaml:controller_vip_name: VXX-osc4.example.com
/var/lib/hiera/vxx-osc4.yaml:controller_vip_name: vxx-osc4.example.com
```

... note that in the file `vxx-osc4.yaml` the value of `controller_vip_name` is `vxx-osc4.example.com`
all lower case and in the defaults.yaml file the value of `controller_vip_name` is `VXX-osc4.example.com`
where VXX is uppercase.  I am trying to QA my set up like so:

```
[root@vxx-osc4-ppt-001 puppetmaster]# hiera controller_vip_name
VXX-osc4.example.com
```

The above command works and hiera retrieves the data from the `defaults.yaml` file 
But this command does not work:

```
[root@vxx-osc4-ppt-001 puppetmaster]# hiera "pod_prefix=vxx-osc4" controller_vip_name
controller_vip_name
```

I think `hiera` completely ignored my `vxx-osc4.yaml` file.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hiera command is wrong:

```
Usage: hiera [options] key [default value] [variable='text'...]
```

Notice that variables come *after* the key.

Comment: Thanks! I should of spotted that.  Hey would you mind looking at this question I posted.  It is slightly related. Its another hiera question. :)